# expanding Excel MATCH function on column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 2 columns in a sheet where the 2nd column is contained in the first. I mark each of them using **MATCH** and it works for a defined range , but when I try to expand the function to the whole column the matching range changes like this:

first line **=MATCH(B1,E1:E277,0)**

second line **=MATCH(B2,E2:E278,0)**

Actually I want to keep the 2nd line range of comparing as the first like this:
    **=MATCH(B2,E1:E277,0)**

And then apply it to the rest of the column (eg: for line 579 I should have **=MATCH(B579,E1:E277,0)**)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer accidentally looking for some resolution. The solution is to use "$" in front of the values that you do not need to change like in this example:

=MATCH(B1,$E$1:$E$277,0)